# Can we make a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++

Is it possible for someone to make a vector full of vectors?

For instance you create a vector where you store all your elements. Then after that, you create a new vector filled with multiple of the the previous vector. If you understand what I mean.

Something like the one below although I am very sure this is not how it works.

```
vector <string> v { First, Second, Third, GPA, Name };
vector <string> newVect { v };
```

Answer (score 6):

You can, but you need to declare the type accordingly:

```cpp
// Define a vector of string
std::vector<std::string> example { "One", "Two", "Three" };

// Define a vector of (vector of string) wrapping another vector of string
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> nested { example };
```

Remember that C++ is *strongly typed* meaning `std::vector<std::string>` can contain `std::string` and *only* `std::string`. Nesting a `std::vector<std::string>` in there is invalid.

That has the effect of *copying* `example` into the new `std::vector`, so that's not the most efficient. Fortunately, you can also define this in one shot:

```cpp
// Define a vector of (vector of string) directly
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> nested { { "One", "Two", "Three" } };
```

To work with this and display the entries, you'll need a nested loop as well, as the structure dictates that:

```cpp
// Iterate over the vector (of vector of string)
for (auto&& outer : nested) {
  // Iterate over the vector (of string)
  for (auto&& inner : outer) {
    std::cout << inner << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: just be carefull with the >> at the end of the declaration, some compiler's syntax analyser don't like it as it can be seen as the '>>' operator. Put a space to avoid this problem.

Comment: @PierreBaret That was a problem, but was addressed in C++11.

Comment: You'll need to deal with the fact that the inner element you're iterating over is now a `std::vector<std::string>` so you can't just dump that in your stream. In other words, you now have *two* levels to iterate over. Also consider `for (auto&& e : v)` to iterate, it's much less fuss.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the response. How do you output it? when I try to cout, the '>>' states that there is no operator that matches the operands

Comment: Added an example there.

Comment: If you're not looking for nesting, but instead *concatenation* then that's different. You can use `insert` to append.

Answer (score 1):

No limitation in how deep you can nest vectors :

```
vector<vector<vector<string> > > my_deep_vector; // this is totally valid
```

You just have to pay attention to what you are manipulating

```
vector<string> v1;
vector<vector<string> > v2;
vector<vector<vector<string> > > v3;

v1.push_back("Hello world");
v2.push_back(v1);
v3.push_back(v2);

// Then you can access the elements similarly to multidimensionnal arrays:
// Please don't judge my old school for loops :P
for (size_t i3 = 0; i3 < v3.size(); i3++)
{
    for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < v3[i3].size(); i2++)
    {
        for (size_t i1 = 0; i1 < v3[i3][i2].size(); i1++)
        {
            cout << v3[i3][i2][i1] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl; // for readability
    }
    cout << endl; // for readability
}
```